# Quiet, low-power Router, DNS and Firewall on a UNIX network?

Tags: router, dns, firewall, adsl

What is the best hardware device for running my DNS, Firewall and acting as a ADSL Router?

Wifi sharing would be nice and running Linux would be a massive advantage too.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the [Linksys WRT54G series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series), preferably with a modded firmware like [Tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_firmware).

Comment: +1 on the WRT54G, but my recommendation is OpenWRT. :)